# Search widget expression

Tags: query, configurable-map-viewer, flex, search

I am trying to migrate my Flex eSearch widget to the CMV Search widget.  The query is not working.  What can I do to make it work? 
Flex query:

```
<value prompt="Example: MN or MNPC">upper(ICAOcode) LIKE upper('%[value]%')</value>
```

CMV query = expression:

`(upper \arpt_name\ LIKE upper \'%[value]%'\)`

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and edit your question to include what you have already tried and what exactly isn't working. If you are receiving an error message, include that. If you are receiving unexpected results, explain what those are vs. what you are expecting.

Answer (score 2):

The only change you should need to make to your original Flex where clause is to escape the single quotes around the value using the slash character:

```
expression: 'upper(ICAOcode) LIKE upper(\'%[value]%\')',
```